# Prevent IIS application cold state

Tags: iis

We have problem with IIS 8.5 application pool turning into some kind of "cold state" which leads to hanging on first request. First of all, you should know that we did homework and found several "solutions" to prevent IIS pool recycling:

```
Application settings: PreloadEnabled = true
Pool settings: StartMode = AlwaysRunning, IdleTimeout = 0, RecyclingInterval = 0
```

These settings keep w3wp.exe process always running - we checked that **process IDs remains the same**. Despite of this, after some period of time some kind of hanging occure when trying to open web-site page. After first opening the problem   disappear for some time and so on.

We start thinking that the cause of it is AppDomain unloading within w3wp.exe process. Can anyone advise where to dig further?

Comment: Stopping the pool from recycling is more often a cause of issues than any issues I can think of that would be solved by doing so.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what issues? Web-site is fully managed code with no memory leaks, and memory consumption is controlled by garbage collector.